Blender IK bones causing positions to swap erratically between positions
World!
As described in the title, a blender model that I'm attempting to animate is experiencing a problem where the bones attached to those of the IK don't seem to be able to decide what position they're in. The bones will even appear in different positions when viewing the same keyframe multiple times.
This is a problem that I've run into before but I've not yet found a reliable solution. I suspect that this problem has a fairly simple solution but I'm having a hell of a time searching for it online.
The image attached shows the IK setup with the bones names set to visible, in case that proves to be helpful.
IK setup
Linked here is a short video that demonstrates the problem, where I move back and forth between frames and the limbs find themselves in different positions.
Thus far I've tried toggling the IK and auto-IK setups, and the removal of an IK does fix the problem, but of course I'm interested in actually using the IK. Changing the chain length does not seem to help or hinder the posing.

I figured out the problem after a while. It turns out that I was running into looped dependencies on the problem bones. I.E., the bone position is informed by the parent but the parent is informed by the IK modifier on the bone. The official Blender advice for this (from version 2.*) is to create an unparented Target bone for one side and an unparented Pole Target bone for the other that sit disconnected from the rig.
